# Electronjs ipcRenderer doesn't send ipcMain response to component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am working on a React and Electron app, and I need to read and write to a user's "userData" folder on their computer. I am using the ipc pattern outlined in the Electron docs for two-way communication, but my React component is just getting an undefined value when I try to use app.getPath(). When I console.log the value in ipcRenderer.invoke, I get the correct value but somewhere inbetween there and my React component it's getting lost.

main.js (relevant ipc code is at the bottom)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, protocol, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');

function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,

        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    const appURL = app.isPackaged
        ? url.format({
                pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
                protocol: 'file:',
                slashes: true
          })
        : 'http://localhost:3000';
    mainWindow.loadURL(appURL);

    if (!app.isPackaged) {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
}

function setupLocalFilesNormalizerProxy() {
    protocol.registerHttpProtocol(
        'file',
        (request, callback) => {
            const url = request.url.substr(8);
            callback({ path: path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${url}`) });
        },
        error => {
            if (error) console.error('Failed to register protocol');
        }
    );
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
    setupLocalFilesNormalizerProxy();

    app.on('activate', function () {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow();
        }
    });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

const allowedNavigationDestinations = 'https://my-electron-app.com';
app.on('web-contents-created', (event, contents) => {
    contents.on('will-navigate', (event, navigationUrl) => {
        const parsedUrl = new URL(navigationUrl);

        if (!allowedNavigationDestinations.includes(parsedUrl.origin)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

ipcMain.on('write-file', (_, filePath, content) => {
    fs.writeFile(filePath, content, function () {
        return 0;
    });
});

ipcMain.handle('get-path', () => {
    let path = app.getPath('userData');
    return path;
});

ipcMain.handle('read-file', () => {
    let path = app.getPath('userData');
    let data = fs.readFileSync(`${path}/tree.json`);
    return data;
});
```

preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

process.once('loaded', () => {
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('versions', process.versions);
});

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    writeFile: (filePath, content) => {
        ipcRenderer.send('write-file', filePath, content);
    },
    getPath: () => {
        ipcRenderer.invoke('get-path'); // when console.logging the result from this I get the correct path
    },
    readFile: () => {
        ipcRenderer.invoke('read-file');
    }
});
```

react component

```
import React from 'react';
// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
// Components
import Note from './components/Note';
import Section from './components/Section';
import IconButton from './components/IconButton';
// Icons
import addIcon from './assets/add.png';
import saveIcon from './assets/save.png';
// Styles
import './styles/App.css';

const App = () => {
    function getSavePath() {
        let path = window.electron.getPath();
        console.log(path); // undefined
    }

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Section />
                <Note />
                <IconButton iconName={addIcon} classes='IconButton-btn-lg IconButton-bot-left' />
                <IconButton
                    iconName={saveIcon}
                    classes='IconButton-btn-lg IconButton-bot-right'
                    action={getSavePath}
                />
            </Provider>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just to make sure I understand you correctly: You want to use `getPath()` to fetch the path from the Main process and then do something with it, right? In that case, it could be as simple as a `return` missing in your `preload.js` functions...

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner huh, that seemed to fix it. Thank you! Yeah I just returned the statement and awaited the response in my react component and I'm getting the path `return ipcRenderer.invoke('get-path');`